# Bag of words Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I need find words training words and their classification. Simple classification such as . Sports Entertainment and Politics things like that.

Where Can i find the words and their classifications. I know many universities have done Bag of words classifications. Is there any repository of training examples ?

Comment: I looked at some of your other questions "Successive adding of char to get the longest word in the dictionary" and can suggest to look at structure named "ternary search tree". You can implement a lot of useful algorithms for searching in list of words and things like spell checking with this structure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately that thread got closed, people were thinking it was some kind of assignment or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know such list of words, but can suggest to use a copy of Wikipedia and wiki classification. You can parse the XML version of Wikipedia (i have done that) and collect words from different topics.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are looking for but you might find http://labs.google.com/sets interesting.
You can put in a bunch of words, and it will spit out a list of related words, which you could recursively throw back into the first page to get even more related words..

Alternatively, download a huge chunk of wikipedia articles (where you already know the category of each page [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Categories ]) and write a simple script to pick words which have high frequency in articles from one category but very low frequency in articles from other categories

Answer (score 1):

You can use 20 newsgroup data http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/20Newsgroups for finding such words per topic. Run a [Support Vector Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) on the data, it will give you weights of words for each class. You can use top 20 or 50 words. The data-set has 20 classes like religion, politics, sports etc. Hope it helps you.